# Which preposition to use with "forum"

Tags: differences, prepositions, collocation

I would hugely appreciate your help thinking through the tagline for a new online forum we are creating.

The current version reads:

> A **Forum on** Our Economy, National Security and Sustainability.

*On* seems to be the most common preposition to follow *forum*, except when there is a gerund involved – e.g., *a forum for discussing, a forum for sharing*, etc.

I would really like to use *about* but that seems unconventional.

Also, if we said

> A **Forum on** National Security, Sustainability, and the/our Economy,

that would seem to work.  But we want *Economy* to be first in the list of three and we don't want to say *Economics* so we went with *our*.

Comment: 'On' is the sensible choice; 'the Economy' sounds more formal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ***the** Economy* is not necessarily ***our** Economy* -- significant here.

Comment: @Kris By the same token, your or their 'our' is not necessarily my 'our'. 'Our' needs context as much as 'the' does here.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost always *forum **for***.

The preposition is followed by the purpose/ objective of the forum, what it aims to provide a platform **for** people to blah-blah on/about/for/against.

*[forum](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forum)*

> **1A** meeting or medium where ideas and views on a particular issue can be exchanged: *we hope these pages act as **a forum for** debate*

Rarely, though, other prepositions find place depending on the intended meaning, different from the usual:

- Forum **of** Regulators/ Donors Forum **of** Wisconsin …
- International Forum **on** Globalization/ United Nations Forum **on** Forests …

[image]

Img. Src.: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forum%20for,forum%20on,forum%20about,forum%20of&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,forum%20for;,c0;.t1;,forum%20on;,c0;.t1;,forum%20about;,c0;.t1;,forum%20of;,c0)

ExecSum: As the phrase is the **subject of interest** (Our Economy …), it would be:

> A Forum **on** Our Economy, National Security and Sustainability.

Answer (score 0):

**Concerning** seems to fit -"about" suggests the audience is less than intelligent